# What does mean by, "full crazy train"?

Tags: idioms

I'm studying English watching TV shows. This week, I was watching *God's Favorite Idiot*, Season 1 Episode 4.

In the scene, Clark, the protagonist asks the god what he should do for the god. Then the god answered his question, mentioning "full crazy train". Do you happen to know what does that mean? Here is the context for your reference:

> Clark: What exactly is the message I'm supposed to get out there?
>
> God: I need you to let people know that God is real and God is good. And everybody, meaning all religions are actually quite right about God. Also, nobody's really wrong. I'm okay with all flavors, unless you're **full crazy train**, or use my name to hurt people.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with the show, but I think you mean "God", not "the god".  When we mean "the one and only supreme creator of the universe", we use *God* as a proper noun.  *the god* just means "one of many possible deities".

Answer (score 2):

"Full crazy train" isn't an expression by itself. It's the adverb "full" and the expression "crazy train".

"Crazy train" comes from the Ozzy Osbourne song "Crazy Train". The refrain from that song is "*I'm going off the rails on a crazy train*". So to say someone is going "crazy train" is a short and humorous way of saying they're "[going off the rails](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20off%20the%20rails)".

The adverb "full" here means "completely".

So someone going "full crazy train" means someone **going completely off the rails**.

In this context, it means God is OK with everyone from any religion, so long as they're not murdering entire civilizations, say, as some religious groups do.